# Get-Content with Wait and processing each line

Tags: powershell

Using `-Match` gives me `True`/`False` values instead of the lines of text.

```
Get-Content ("\\path”) -tail 10 -wait | % {
    foreach ($data in ($_ -match "Execute")) {
        $First = $data.Substring(26,37).Trim()
        Write-Host $First
    }
}
```

I used below code without `-tail -wait` to do what I, but I can't change to parsing the file using `-tail` with `Get-Content`.

```
$DB = Get-Content ("\\path”) -tail -ReadCount 5000000  | foreach { $_ -match "string to match" } | foreach{ $_.Trim()}  

foreach ($Data in $DB) {
    $First = $Data.Substring(26,37).Trim()
    $Second = $Data
    Write-Host $First
    Write-Host $Second
}
```

Comment: Match gives the boolean result of whether anything was found.  The results then appear in $matches.

Comment: Thank you very match got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-match` expression returns a boolean result, but also updates a special variable, `$matches`.

You can filter lines by using `-match` in a `where-object` expression to return only those lines which match.

```
$myFilteredArray = $myArray | where-object{$_ -match 'execute'}
```

If using it for something that simple though, you may as well use `-like`:

```
$myFilteredArray = $myArray | where-object{$_ -like '*execute*'}
```

If you want to be clever, you can also use regular expressions; that way `$matches` will hold all captured groups (including a special group named `0` which holds the original line).

**Simple Example / plain text search**

```
@(
    'line 1 - please '
    ,'line 2 - execute'
    ,'line 3 - this'
    ,'line 4 - script'
) | where-object {$_ -match 'execute'} | foreach-object{
    "-Match found the following matches:"
    $matches
    "The line giving this result was"
    $_
}
```

**Example using Regex / capturing group**

```
@(
    'line 1 - please '
    ,'line 2 - execute'
    ,'line 3 - this'
    ,'line 4 - script'
) | where-object {$_ -match '(?<capturedData>.*?)(?: - )execute'} | foreach-object{
    "-Match found the following matches:"
    $matches
    "The line giving this result was"
    $_
}
```

- `-match`: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html
- `-like`, `-match`, and other comparisons: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can array-cast your `$_`, like this:

```
foreach ($data in (,$_ -match "Execute")) {
```

Here's the output difference:

```
$data=@("bla bla","foo bla","foo bar","bla bar")
PS > $data | % { foreach ($a in ($_ -match "bla")){$a}}
True
True
False
True
PS > $data | % { foreach ($a in (,$_ -match "bla")){$a}}
bla bla
foo bla
bla bar
```

Comment: works perfectly thank u - i used this solution to solve it.

Comment: One more question - need to put a wildacard in a path to parse few files in a destination path : \\host\Logs\name*date.log. So i put a "*" in a path, but if think it's not working well. No output at all.

Comment: You probably need to check first if your `$_` has more than 1 element. If yes, match directly, if not, match with array-cast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `-match` when applied to a scalar returns a boolean result. When applied to an array it returns the matching elements. In your second example you use `ReadCount` to force `Get-Content` to send more than a line through the pipeline at a time. Of course you're then getting an array of lines every time instead of just a line, thus changing the semantics of `-match`.

To make your first example work, simply change `foreach` into `if`.